# Memory Warning UIImagepickerController IOS 7

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimagepickercontroller, ios7, didreceivememorywarning

Could anybody help me with this issue  I'm a bit new to objective c and iOS. I've been working on it but I can't figure out how to fix the problem, My app is really simple it only start the camera take pictures and send them through email to our server. This code was working just fine in iOS6.

When I take pictures my memory is heap growth with each screen capture and I get "Received Memory Warning" and finally - Terminated due to Memory Pressure. -

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

[self.popoverController2 dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
NSString *mediaType = [info
                       objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    _image = [info
                      objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

   _image = [self fixrotation:_image]; //<----- increased memory when UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum is uncommented IF is comment it doesn't increased memory but after some pictures I start to get "Received Memory Warning" message until the app Crash.

    if (_newMedia){
       UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_image,
                                       self,@selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                       nil);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SeleccionadoCameraR" sender:self];


    }else{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SeleccionadoCameraR" sender:self];

    }

}

}

- (UIImage *)fixrotation:(UIImage *)image{


if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return image;
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

switch (image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, image.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        break;
}

switch (image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.height, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        break;
}

// Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
// calculated above.
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, image.size.width, image.size.height,
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image.CGImage), 0,
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                         CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image.CGImage));


CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
switch (image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        // Grr...
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.height,image.size.width), image.CGImage);
        break;

    default:
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height), image.CGImage); //when I use instruments it shows that My VM is because of this 
        break;
}

// And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);//also this line in Instruments
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];


CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(cgimg);


return img;


 }
```

probably is a memory management. I will appreciate your help

Comment: Run the static analyzer to see if there are any warnings. Then run the app in Instruments and look for any leaks and retain cycles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track with your `fixRotation` method. However, you should also **resize** the image. Otherwise, the image will be huge, ~30 MB (depending on device).

Checkout [this blog post](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) on how to resize images correctly. Specifically, the `UIImage` category files you want are these:

[UIImage+Resize.h](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/UIImage+Resize.h)

[UIImage+Resize.m](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/UIImage+Resize.m)

It's also a good idea to do this on a background thread. Something like this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Dismiss the image picker first to free its memory
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (!originalImage)
        return;

    // Optionally set a placeholder image here while resizing happens in background

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Set desired maximum height and calculate width
        CGFloat height = 640.0f;  // or whatever you need
        CGFloat width = (height / originalImage.size.height) * originalImage.size.width;

        // Resize the image
        UIImage * image = [originalImage resizedImage:CGSizeMake(width, height) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];

        // Optionally save the image here...

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // ... Set / use the image here...
        });           
    });
}
```

Comment: i've resized it, the memory increase was reduced, but it continues increasing a bit slower until my app crash, somehow I need to clean memory

Comment: First of All I stated a new project with iOS7 with the same Classes  and methods and finally I resized images to 640 x 480 and 480 X 640 and then I applied fixRotation Method, my memory increases once but with other photos it doesn't.

Comment: @cesartrujillocetina Can you show your final working code? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum method use 30M+ memory on iOS7.It's not about your resize or fixrotation method.

Comment: I also have the same problem.. is any one got solution?

Comment: Yes man, every time that i call UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum my app receive a memory warning!! And obviously crash!

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by JRG-Developer-s answer up here
with a little modifications:
I `m using categories to fix orientation of image ans scaling it down before presenting
and when done, I call Weak Self to assign this scaled and fixed image to my imageview)

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{    
    UIImage *lvImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //CGSize pickedImageSize = lvImage.size;
    if (postHandler == nil)
    {
        postHandler = [[PostHandler alloc] init];
    }

    //_postItemImageView.image = lvImage;
    //postHandler.wholeScreenImage = lvImage;// to proceed editing, cropping, tagging ...
    //_postItemImageView.image = postHandler.wholeScreenImage; set in viewWillAppear
    __weak PostPrepareViewController *weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
    {

        // Resize the image
        UIImage * scaledImage = [[lvImage imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:_postItemImageView.frame.size] fixOrientation];
        // Optionally save the image here...
        //CGSize scaledimageSize = scaledImage.size;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            postHandler.wholeScreenImage = scaledImage;
            [weakSelf didScaleDownImage];
        });           
    });


    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        [self.popOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

and lower:

```
-(void) didScaleDownImage
{
   _postItemImageView.image = postHandler.wholeScreenImage;
}
```

code of scaling was taken from the net:

```
-(UIImage *)imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:(CGSize)targetSize
{
    UIImage *sourceImage = self;
    UIImage *newImage = nil;
    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;
    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;
    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO)
    {
        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
        {
            scaleFactor = widthFactor; // scale to fit height
        }
        else
        {
            scaleFactor = heightFactor; // scale to fit width
        }

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image
        if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5;
        }
        else
        {
            if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
            {
                thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
            }
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize); // this will crop
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetSize, 1.0, 0.0);

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");
    }

    //pop the context to get back to the default
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

and code for changing (fixing) image orientation was also taken from the net:

```
- (UIImage *)fixOrientation
{    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
   //
    return img;
}
```

please, don-t be cruel in minusing if something looks dummy) I-m junior for now)

For answer below - that s why you would better scale down an image - to take less memory in use, but not simply save the big 4MB image to disc. At the very begining I also had memory issues - it was eating 30Mb per sigle photo - and I had to take 2 photos one by one... now it works fine and smooth.
Fix orientation is optional, but I would recommend anyway to scale down photo - resize it to smaller.