# ImagePicker loads very long for the second time

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a problem with iOS ImagePicker. It works correctly, but when I want to take another photo the camera loads for a very long time (first time: 1-2sec, second time and later: 8-10sec). This is how I use it:

```
- (void)takePhoto {
    _imagePicker = [UIImagePickerController new];
    _imagePicker.delegate = self;
    _imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentViewController:_imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and this is how I get the image:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    [_imagePickerView.imageView setImage:image];
}
```

I don't see there much place for bugs. Of course I implement protocols `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

Do you have any ideas how can I figure out what is causing this?

Comment: Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061510/memory-warning-uiimagepickercontroller-ios-7). It has to do with very large images you are loading with ``imagePickerController``. You should scale them down.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to dismiss the UIImagePickerController after you picked an item by calling

```
[_imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

It should be fine, now.

Comment: I was not an issue, I'm still trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your first block of code to reuse the same imagePicker you have already initialized:

```
- (void)takePhoto {
    if(_imagePicker == nil)
        _imagePicker = [UIImagePickerController new];
    _imagePicker.delegate = self;
    _imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentViewController:_imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I was not an issue, I'm still trying to fix it.